# JSON data(response entity) showing object value as integer

Tags: javascript, json

As I check the response JSON data using `Stringify()`.

I get the data of array as an integer, e.g. `"cfQmsType": 3`

but expected:

```
cfQmsType: {
    "@id": 5,
    "qmsTypeCde": "5106",
    "description": "TAILORED",
    "qmsType": "TAILORED"
}
```

I have checked the data from response in the business logic in which I get the data.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you are asking here.

Comment: The cfQmsType is an array object and therefore the expected data as shown above whereas the response that is returned has only an integer value eg., 3 or 1 instead of the array  object.If the no. of occurrences is 7, then there would mix of integer value and array object.As shown above both the data are the JSON response only but one is correct(array) and the other is an integer value 3.

Comment: This issue is still not resolved, hence any help is appreciated.